# How to make instance one time and use it more times?

Tags: java

I should write an application for handling math operations. I have one interface `Operator` and four classes `Plus`, `Minus`, `Multiply`, `Divide`). These interface and classes are in separate folders. I should load and use them in my main program. I do it like so:

```
File operatorFile = new File(operatorPath);
URL operatorFilePath = operatorFile.toURL();          
URL[] operatorFilePaths = new URL[]{operatorFilePath};
ClassLoader operatorsLoader = new URLClassLoader(operatorFilePaths);




Class operatorInterface = operatorsLoader.loadClass("operators.Operator"); 

            FilenameFilter dotClassFilter = new FilenameFilter() 
            { 
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
                { 
                    return name.endsWith(".class"); 
                } 
            };
while(expression != null)
            {
                String[] elementInExpression = expression.split(",");

                if(elementInExpression.length != 3)
                {
                    System.out.println("Expression should have two operand and 1 operator ");
                    throw new ValidationException("Validation on number of element failed1");
                }

                Validation.validateOperand(elementInExpression[0],elementInExpression[1]);
                Validation.validateOperator(elementInExpression[2]);

                double firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(elementInExpression[0]);
                double secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(elementInExpression[1]);

                double output = 0;

                Method methodsInOperator;
                Object instance;
                String operatorSign;

                for(Class operatorCls : operatorClass)
                {
                    instance = operatorCls.newInstance();
                    methodsInOperator = operatorCls.getMethod("getSign", null); 
                    operatorSign = (String)methodsInOperator.invoke(instance, null);
                    if(operatorSign.equals(elementInExpression[2]))
                    {
                        methodsInOperator = operatorCls.getMethod("calculate", new Class[] { double.class, double.class } ); 
                        output =(double)methodsInOperator.invoke(instance, firstNumber, secondNumber);  
                    }
                }

                processingResult.add(output);
                expression = mathExpReader.readLine();
            }
```

but at the below statement I make an instance for every line I read from file and in this way waste memory. Is there any way to make an instance one time and use it several times?

```
for(Class operatorCls : operatorClass)
                {
                    instance = operatorCls.newInstance(); //here we waste memory
                    methodsInOperator = operatorCls.getMethod("getSign", null); 
                    operatorSign = (String)methodsInOperator.invoke(instance, null);
                    if(operatorSign.equals(elementInExpression[2]))
                    {
                        methodsInOperator = operatorCls.getMethod("calculate", new Class[] { double.class, double.class } ); 
                        output =(double)methodsInOperator.invoke(instance, firstNumber, secondNumber);  
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create class using singleton pattern then you have to initialize object once and you can use it anywhere in project.

[here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm) is tutorial of singleton pattern.

Comment: Sorry when I make Singelton class Where should I use in my program?if I use in while loop I think the problem don't solve Can u help me?

Comment: If you have implement singleton then you have static method getInstance which is accessible every where.This method will create instance first time and next time return same object which created before.
There are different ways to implement singleton pattern,you can search out for better understanding.There will be no issue in using loops or anywhere else.Singleton will never create more than object.